# problems with read/write in samba share between 2 computers

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba

I'm making a samba conexion between 2 ubuntu 20.04 LTS computers.

have the folder created and shared with SMB3 server,have specified write permissions and have mounted the folder in my linux samba client and the files are synced

the only problem is that,if I create a file/folder in the server computer,the client computer has 0 rights,no read or write,and I need them to have both.

tried from root users and same,no acces no change permissions no open files no execute,nothing.

already checked and if I create the folder/file in the client pc both have full permisions.

here is my samba server conf:

```
[sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /mnt/sharedfolder
    read only = no
    writeable = Yes
    browsable = yes
    create mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
```

and here's my mount command (*** equals to my SMB username)

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=*** //192.168.***.***/sambashare /mnt/sharedfolder_client/
```

Any idea about what could be happening? I tried to acces samba folder from windows to see if same happened but unsucessfull,says the samba folder doesn't exist.